# How to display a system account with the highest user id

Tags: linux, shell-script, pipe, passwd, etc

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
bin:x:1:1:bin:/bin:/sbin/nologin
daemon:x:2:2:daemon:/sbin:/sbin/nologin
adm:x:3:4:adm:/var/adm:/sbin/nologin
lp:x:4:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/sbin/nologin
sync:x:5:0:sync:/sbin:/bin/sync
shutdown:x:6:0:shutdown:/sbin:/sbin/shutdown
halt:x:7:0:halt:/sbin:/sbin/halt
mail:x:8:12:mail:/var/spool/mail:/sbin/nologin
operator:x:11:0:operator:/root:/sbin/nologin
games:x:12:100:games:/usr/games:/sbin/nologin
ftp:x:14:50:FTP User:/var/ftp:/sbin/nologin
nobody:x:99:99:Nobody:/:/sbin/nologin
systemd-network:x:192:192:systemd Network Management:/:/sbin/nologin
dbus:x:81:81:System message bus:/:/sbin/nologin
polkitd:x:999:998:User for polkitd:/:/sbin/nologin
ntp:x:38:38::/etc/ntp:/sbin/nologin
sshd:x:74:74:Privilege-separated SSH:/var/empty/sshd:/sbin/nologin
postfix:x:89:89::/var/spool/postfix:/sbin/nologin
chrony:x:998:996::/var/lib/chrony:/sbin/nologin
adilfanta:x:1000:1001::/home/adilfanta:/bin/bash
scripty:x:1001:1002::/home/scripty:/bin/bash
brencklen1:x:1002:1003::/home/brencklen1:/bin/bash
```

So above I have a list of system accounts. I am trying to figure out how I can display a system account with the highest user id.
For example, let's say I only want to display this

```
script:x:1001:1002::/home/script:/bin/bash

cat /etc/passwd | grep scripty
```

I was gonna do this grep command above but I can not assume script has highest user id for every system.

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F':' '$3 > maxid{ maxid=$3; line=$0 } END{ print line }' /etc/passwd
```